# Quartz job execution null pointer exception

Tags: spring-boot, quartz-scheduler

When quartz trigger the job execution HoldingService.unHold() method throw null pointer exception.

```
   public class SampleJob extends QuartzJobBean {
        @Autowired
        private HoldingService holdingService;
    @Override
        public void executeInternal(JobExecutionContext context) throws JobExecutionException {
            holdingService.unHold();
        }
    }
```

**Services**

```
public interface HoldingService {
    void unHold();
}

@Service("HoldingService")
@Scope("prototype")
public class HoldingServiceImpl implements HoldingService {
    @Override
    public void unHoldCycle() {}

}
```

Comment: You're autowiring holdingService but invoking cycleHoldingService in `executeInternal`. What's that?

Comment: @jp86 sorry for that its a mistake..question updated.

Comment: i believe the problem might be with the `@Scope("prototype")` of `HoldingServiceImpl`. Do you really need it to be prototype scoped? If so, you could remove the `@Autowired` and look it up from the application context before using it in the `executeInternal` method